# Scale equation in NewEnviron

Tags: environments, scalebox

I write my long equations through a created environment `nr` that allows vertical alignment and manual breaking of the equations:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\DeclareMathSizes{10}{18}{12}{8} % this option is for inline equations  
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{adjustbox}  
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewEnviron{nr}[2]{%  
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{#1}  
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{#1}  
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{#2}  
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{#2}  
{\color{white}\hrule}    
\begin{equation*}  
\begin{split}  
\BODY  
\end{split}  
\end{equation*}  
%\vskip 0mm  
}  

\begin{document}  

\begin{nr}{5pt}{0pt}&
\frac{1}{2}\cdot m\cdot v^2_{2,x}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot m\cdot v^2_{2,y}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot m\cdot v^2_{2,z}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot m\cdot v^2_{1,x}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot m\cdot v^2_{1,y}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot m\cdot v^2_{1,z}=\\&=
\int\limits^2_1{F_{\mathrm{net,x}}\cdot {dl}_x}+\int\limits^2_1{F_{\mathrm{net,y}}\cdot {dl}_y}+\int\limits^2_1{F_{\mathrm{net,z}}\cdot {dl}_z}
\end{nr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want that equation to be bigger, but failed to add `\scalebox` or any other scaling tool to the `NewEnviron`. The `\DeclareMathSizes` declares size of my inline equations.
How can I rescale the given equation?

Comment: Not the solution to your problem, but your posted code is missing `\usepackage{color}` or `\usepackage{xcolor}`

Comment: You need to put the equation inisde a minipage of width `{\dimexpr \textwidth/scale}` so that is scales back to \textwidth.

Comment: your equation is already to big that can be fit in text width. so first you need first to broken it in more lines, than you can simply wrote as `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\huge
\[ \begin{split}
... \end{split}\] \end{minipage}`

Answer (score 1):

I scaled the equation with `resizebox` inside `minibox`. Now the math expressions with fractions or integrals have perfect vertical spacing. Nevertheless the math without fractions/integrals contains unwanted top vertical space, as can be seen from the example:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\DeclareMathSizes{10}{18}{12}{8} % this option is for inline equations  
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{adjustbox}  
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewEnviron{nr}[2]{%
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{#1}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{#1}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{#2}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{#2}
\resizebox{1.1\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{minipage}[l]{\textwidth}
{\color{black}\hrule}
\vskip 0mm
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\BODY
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\vskip 0mm
\end{minipage}
}}

\begin{document}

Definujme v~bodě tělesa $\overrightarrow{V}$ o objemu $dV$ element veličiny hybnost $\overrightarrow{dp}(dV)$:

\begin{nr}{0pt}{0pt}
\overrightarrow{dp}(dV)\equiv \overrightarrow{v}\cdot dm(dV)
\end{nr}

kde $\overrightarrow{v}$ je rychlost v bodě tělesa $\overrightarrow{V}$ a $dm$ je hmotnost elementu.\vskip 10pt

V libovolném bodě tělesa $\overrightarrow{V}$ je derivace elementu hybnosti podle času:

\begin{nr}{0pt}{0pt}
\frac{d\left(\overrightarrow{dp}\left(dV\right)\right)}{d\tau }=\frac{d}{d\tau }\left(\overrightarrow{v}\cdot dm(dV)\right)
\end{nr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How one can unify the vertical spacing in those equations?

Answer (score 1):

Here, I applay the `\scalebox` to a `\vbox` of the `nr` environemnt.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\DeclareMathSizes{10}{18}{12}{8} % this option is for inline equations  
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{adjustbox}  
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewEnviron{nr}[2]{%  
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{#1}  
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{#1}  
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{#2}  
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{#2}  
{\color{white}\hrule}    
\begin{equation*}  
\begin{split}  
\BODY  
\end{split}  
\end{equation*}  
%\vskip 0mm  
}  

\begin{document}  

\begin{nr}{5pt}{0pt}&
\frac{1}{2}\cdot m\cdot v^2_{2,x}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot m\cdot v^2_{2,y}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot m\cdot v^2_{2,z}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot m\cdot v^2_{1,x}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot m\cdot v^2_{1,y}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot m\cdot v^2_{1,z}=\\&=
\int\limits^2_1{F_{\mathrm{net,x}}\cdot {dl}_x}+\int\limits^2_1{F_{\mathrm{net,y}}\cdot {dl}_y}+\int\limits^2_1{F_{\mathrm{net,z}}\cdot {dl}_z}
\end{nr}

{\centering\scalebox{.7}{\vbox{
\begin{nr}{5pt}{0pt}&
\frac{1}{2}\cdot m\cdot v^2_{2,x}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot m\cdot v^2_{2,y}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot m\cdot v^2_{2,z}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot m\cdot v^2_{1,x}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot m\cdot v^2_{1,y}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot m\cdot v^2_{1,z}=\\&=
\int\limits^2_1{F_{\mathrm{net,x}}\cdot {dl}_x}+\int\limits^2_1{F_{\mathrm{net,y}}\cdot {dl}_y}+\int\limits^2_1{F_{\mathrm{net,z}}\cdot {dl}_z}
\end{nr}}}\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]